# Map repositions and zooms on overlay on/off

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a map with overlay images... all work fine, but whenever I turn one of the overlays on/off the entire map redraws (re-positioning the map and changing the zoom level). What needs to change in the code to maintain the map position and zoom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>GISM</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style>
       html, body, #map_canvas {
         margin: 0px;
         padding: 0px;
         height: 100%;
       }
       #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25px;
        left: 85%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: (255,255,255);
        padding: 15px;
        opacity: 0.64;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 233px;
      }

      #latlong {
        opacity: 0.64;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -199px;
        left: 55555   margin-left: -60px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 5px;
        //border: 1px solid #999;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        height: 300px;
      }

     </style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var layers = [];//from kmlonoff
        var map = null;
        var overlays = [];
        var boundsArray = [];
////////////////////////////latlon marker begin//////////////////////////////////
        var marker = null;

    // popup window for pin, if in use
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
        size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
        });

    // A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
    function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {

    var contentString = html;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');    
    return marker;

}   
//////////////////////////////latlon marker end////////////////////////////////// 

///////a function to change the button color called from html code onclick= below////// from http://jsfiddle.net/ku2Ye/10/////
function colorchange(id)
{

  var background = document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor;

  if(background === "rgb(211, 211, 211)")
  {
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "rgb(26,255,0)";
  }
  if(background === "rgb(26, 255, 0)")
  {
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "rgb(211,211,211)";
  }

}

///colorchange function end////////////////////


        SchipholOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

function initialize()
        {
                // sets the location of the initial pin (not map or redraw location, just the crosshair)
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.926315,168.0);//from kmlonoff
            var mapProp = { //set map properties
                    center:new google.maps.LatLng(22.309213, 175.762316),
                    minZoom: 3,
                    zoom: 4,// sets the initial zoom before any overlays are added
                    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                    };

          //create map variable with properties       
            map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
            var image1 = 'images/sa.png'; //fromkmlonoff
            var layersLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-41.356341319572,147.41842480153);//from kmlonoff
            var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(-50.19625231313214, -344.0500);
            var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(62.09090138143704, -136.00001614726723);
            var swBound2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-9.99625231313214, -180.7500);
            var neBound2 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.99090138143704, -75.56001614726723);
            var swBound3 = new google.maps.LatLng(-45.0125231313214, -344.0500);
            var neBound3 = new google.maps.LatLng(44.5090138143704, -66.00001614726723);
            var swBound4 = new google.maps.LatLng(10.5125231313214, 114.7500);
            var neBound4 = new google.maps.LatLng(34.3090138143704, 151.30001614726723);    
            var swBound5 = new google.maps.LatLng(1.20, 101.20);
        var neBound5 = new google.maps.LatLng(42.0, 165.04);
            var swBound6 = new google.maps.LatLng(-49.20, -325.20); 
            var neBound6 = new google.maps.LatLng(60.0, -109.8);
        var swBound7 = new google.maps.LatLng(-67.0, 10.0);
        var neBound7 = new google.maps.LatLng(67.0, -82.5); 
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);
            var bounds2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound2, neBound2);
            var bounds3 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound3, neBound3);
            var bounds4 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound4, neBound4);
        var bounds5 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound5, neBound5);
        var bounds6 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound6, neBound6);
        var bounds7 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound7, neBound7);
            boundsArray.push(bounds);
            boundsArray.push(bounds2);
            boundsArray.push(bounds3);
        boundsArray.push(bounds4);  
        boundsArray.push(bounds5);
            boundsArray.push(bounds6);
        boundsArray.push(bounds7);
            // Insert overlay image here
        var srcImage = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/JTWC_ARCHIVE/2015/STREAMLINE_CHARTS/AORoverlay.png';//0
        var srcImage1 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/wx/products/${streamtimeWP}/aor/gfs/${streamtimeWP}.aor.gfs.hjd.000nm.png';//1
            var srcImage2 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/wx/products/${streamtimeWP}/aor/nvg/${streamtimeWP}.aor.nvg.hjd.000nm.png';//
            var srcImage3 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/JTWC_ARCHIVE/${YYYY}/STREAMLINE_CHARTS/SURFACE/SFC${streamtimeWP}.png';//3
            var srcImage4 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/JTWC_ARCHIVE/${YYYY}/STREAMLINE_CHARTS/SURFACE/SFCs${streamtimeWP}.png';//4
            var srcImage5 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/JTWC_ARCHIVE/${YYYY}/STREAMLINE_CHARTS/SURFACE/SFCa${streamtimeWP}.png';//5
            var srcImage6 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/JTWC_ARCHIVE/${YYYY}/STREAMLINE_CHARTS/EPAC/SURFACE/SFCs${streamtimeEP}.png';//6
            var srcImage7 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/JTWC_ARCHIVE/${YYYY}/STREAMLINE_CHARTS/EPAC/SURFACE/SFCa${streamtimeEP}.png';//7
            var srcImage8 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/JTWC_ARCHIVE/${YYYY}/STREAMLINE_CHARTS/UPPER_AIR/UA${streamtimeWP}.png';//8
        var srcImage9 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/wx/products/${streamtimeWP}/aor/gfs/${streamtimeWP}.aor.gfs.efa.000.png';//1
     //   var srcImage9 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/JTWC_ARCHIVE/Models/gfs/${streamtimeWP}.aor.gfs.hjd.000nm.png';//1
        var srcImage10 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/wx/products/${streamtimeWP}/aor/nvg/${streamtimeWP}.aor.nvg.efa.000.png';//2
        var srcImage11 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/JTWC_ARCHIVE/${YYYY}/STREAMLINE_CHARTS/UPPER_AIR/UAs${streamtimeWP}.png';//9
            var srcImage12 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/JTWC_ARCHIVE/${YYYY}/STREAMLINE_CHARTS/UPPER_AIR/UAa${streamtimeWP}.png';//10
            var srcImage13 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/JTWC_ARCHIVE/${YYYY}/STREAMLINE_CHARTS/EPAC/UPPER_AIR/UAs${streamtimeEP}.png';//11
            var srcImage14 = 'https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/JTWC_ARCHIVE/${YYYY}/STREAMLINE_CHARTS/EPAC/UPPER_AIR/UAa${streamtimeEP}.png';//12
            var srcImage15 = 'http://rammb.cira.colostate.edu/ramsdis/online/images/latest/himawari-8/tropics_band_03.gif';//13    
            var srcImage16 = 'http://rammb.cira.colostate.edu/ramsdis/online/images/latest/himawari-8/himawari-8_band_13_sector_06.gif';//14
            //this determines the draw order//
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map));
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds7, srcImage1, map));
        overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds7, srcImage2, map));
        overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds, srcImage3, map));
        overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds, srcImage4, map));
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds, srcImage5, map));
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds2, srcImage6, map));
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds2, srcImage7, map));
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds, srcImage8, map));
        overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds7, srcImage9, map));
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds7, srcImage10, map));
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds, srcImage11, map));
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds, srcImage12, map));
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds2, srcImage13, map));
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds2, srcImage14, map));
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds5, srcImage15, map));
            overlays.push(new SchipholOverlay(bounds5, srcImage14, map));
              //          layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Region/GroundOverlay/usa-ca-sf.kml', {preserveViewport:true});
        layers[1] = new google.maps.KmlLayer(' file:///C:/Users/james.darlow/Documents/NetBeansProjects/GISM/public_html/MTSAT_ir.kml', {preserveViewport:true});
            layers[1].setMap(map);
            layers[2] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.usno.navy.mil/NOOC/nmfc-ph/RSS/jtwc/warnings/wp2015.kmz', {preserveViewport:true});
            layers[2].setMap(map);
           // layers[3] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://www.nrlmry.navy.mil/tcdat/tc16/SHEM/08S.CORENTIN/kml/2016_SHEM_08S.main.kml', {preserveViewport:true});
           // layers[3].setMap(map);
            layers[4] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/sat/MTSAT_ir.kmz', {preserveViewport:true});
        //layers[4] = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://ohana.nmci.navy.mil/sat/MTSAT_ir.kmz', {preserveViewport:true});
            layers[4].setMap(map);
            bounds.extend(layersLatLng);




///// start kml TDO /////
  var TDOKMZLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'https://10.32.63.99/mediawiki-1.5.4/JTWC/Figures/StormData/JTWC_GOOGLE_EARTH.kmz',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map
  });

/////// start kml NRL TC /////
  var WstormsLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.nrlmry.navy.mil/tcdat/tc15/IO/93A.INVEST/kml/2015_IO_91A.main.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map
  });        


////// start latlon pin////////////           
                // establish the initial marker/pin
// var image = 'crosshair2.png';  
//    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
//      position: myLatlng,
//      map: map,
//      title:"Property Loca",
    //the below code is meant to adjust marker positions from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex  
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
//    size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
//    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
//    anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 25),
//    icon: image
//    });


    // establish the initial div form fields
    formlat = document.getElementById("latbox").value = myLatlng.lat();
    formlng = document.getElementById("lngbox").value = myLatlng.lng();

    // close popup window
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });

    // removing old markers/pins
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        //call function to create marker
         if (marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
            marker = null;
         }

        // Information for popup window if you so chose to have one
        /*
         marker = createMarker(event.latLng, "name", "<b>Location</b><br>"+event.latLng);
        */

        //var image = 'crosshair2.png';
        var image = {
            url: 'crosshair2.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 25)
        };
//        var myLatLng = event.latLng ;
        /*  
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            by removing the 'var' subsquent pin placement removes the old pin icon
        */
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({   
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            draggable:true,
            title:"drag me",
            zIndex: 9
        });
        /*
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({   
            position: myLatLng,
            center: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title:"Property Loco",
            size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(25, 25),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 25)
        });
        */


        // populate the form fields with lat & lng 
          formlat = document.getElementById("latbox").value = event.latLng.lat();
          formlng = document.getElementById("lngbox").value = event.latLng.lng();

      });

        }

/////end lat long marker/////////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////begin of kmlonoff function/////////////////
function toggleLayer(i) {
  if(layers[i].getMap() === null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  } else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
////end of kmlonoff function////////////////////

        function SchipholOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

        // Now initialize all properties.
        this.bounds_ = bounds;
        this.image_ = image;
        this.map_ = map;

        // We define a property to hold the image's
        // div. We'll actually create this div
        // upon receipt of the add() method so we'll
        // leave it null for now.
        this.div_ = null;

        // Explicitly call setMap() on this overlay
        this.setMap(map);
        }


        SchipholOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

          // Note: an overlay's receipt of onAdd() indicates that
          // the map's panes are now available for attaching
          // the overlay to the map via the DOM.

          // Create the DIV and set some basic attributes.
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
          div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
          div.style.position = 'absolute';
          div.style.visibility = 'hidden';// al aded this to hide the charts onload



          // Create an IMG element and attach it to the DIV.
          var img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = this.image_;
          img.style.width = '100%';
          img.style.height = '100%';
//          img.style.position = 'absolute';
          div.appendChild(img);

          // Set the overlay's div_ property to this DIV
          this.div_ = div;

          // We add an overlay to a map via one of the map's panes.
          // We'll add this overlay to the overlayLayer pane.
          var panes = this.getPanes();
          panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
        }

        SchipholOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

          // Size and position the overlay. We use a southwest and northeast
          // position of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
          // We need to retrieve the projection from this overlay to do this.
          var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

          // Retrieve the southwest and northeast coordinates of this overlay
          // in latlngs and convert them to pixels coordinates.
          // We'll use these coordinates to resize the DIV.
          var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
          var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

          // Resize the image's DIV to fit the indicated dimensions.
          var div = this.div_;
          div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
          div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
          div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
          div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
        };

        SchipholOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
            this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
            //this.div_ = null;
            };

        SchipholOverlay.prototype.hide = function() {
            if (this.div_) {
                this.div_.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
            };

        SchipholOverlay.prototype.show = function() {
            if (this.div_) {
                this.div_.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            };

        SchipholOverlay.prototype.toggle = function() {
            if (this.div_) {
              if (this.div_.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
                    this.show();
                } else {
                    this.hide();
                }
            }
        }


        //initialize the map
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
   </head>
   <body>
<div id ="panel">
        <IMG SRC="technodev3.png" ALT="some text" WIDTH=60 HEIGHT=60>
        <h1>GISM</h1>
        <h3>Low Levels</h3>
        <input type="button" value="Overlay" id="Overlay" onclick="colorchange('Overlay');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[0].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="SFC GFS" id="SFC GFS" onclick="colorchange('SFC GFS');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[1].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="SFC NVG" id="SFC NVG" onclick="colorchange('SFC NVG');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[2].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="Chart" id="Chart" onclick="colorchange('Chart');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[3].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="Streamline" id="Streamline" onclick="colorchange('Streamline');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[4].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="Analysis" id="Analysis" onclick="colorchange('Analysis');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[5].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="EPAC Streamline" id="EPAC Streamline" onclick="colorchange('EPAC Streamline');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[6].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="EPAC Analysis" id="EPAC Analysis" onclick="colorchange('EPAC Analysis');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[7]);overlays[5].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <h3>Upper Levels</h3>
        <input type="button" value="Chart" id="ULChart" onclick="colorchange('ULChart');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[8].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="UA GFS" id="UA GFS" onclick="colorchange('UA GFS');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[9].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="UA NVG" id="UA NVG" onclick="colorchange('UA NVG');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[10].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="Streamline" id="ULStreamline" onclick="colorchange('ULStreamline');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[11].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="Analysis" id="ULAnalysis" onclick="colorchange('ULAnalysis');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[12].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="EPAC Streamline" id="EPAC ULStreamline" onclick="colorchange('EPAC ULStreamline');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[13].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="EPAC Analysis" id="EPAC ULAnalysis" onclick="colorchange('EPAC ULAnalysis');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[14].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="Himawari VIS" id="Himawari VIS" onclick="colorchange('Himawari VIS');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[15].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>
    <input type="button" value="Himawari Band 13" id="Himawari Band 13" onclick="colorchange('Himawari Band 13');map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);overlays[16].toggle();" style="background:rgb(211,211,211);"/><br>        
</div>
        <div class="map" id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>

   <div id="latlong">
    <p>Latitude: <input size="5" type="text" id="latbox" name="lat" ></p>
    <p>Longitude: <input size="5" type="text" id="lngbox" name="lng" ></p>
  </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You need to remove the code that causes the map to recenter and zoom when the buttons are clicked. (i.e. `map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);`)

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much geocodezip.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the code that causes the map to recenter and zoom when the buttons are clicked. (i.e. map.fitBounds(boundsArray[0]);)